# WebSocket stops receiving data after 15 - 20 minutes of data stream - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets

Code

```
var websock = net.createServer(function(sock) {
  sock.pipe(sock);
  sock.setEncoding('utf8');
  sock.setKeepAlive(true);

  sock.on("data", function(d) {
       console.log("websock", d);
  });

  sock.on('end', function() {
      console.log('websock disconnected');
  });
});

websock.listen(777, '127.0.0.1');
```

After few minutes ~15 mins the callback code in sock.on("data", function() {}) seems not to be working. why is it the case? I checked the console.log, there is no log with a string "websock disconnected".

if the socket is not disconnected and if there is no error, what has happened to the socket connection or the data stream?

On the other end, (Server side, data sender) seems to be streaming data continuously while client side (nodejs app) has stopped receiving data.

Comment: I think it is about ping and pong...your server or client may be failed to send ping and pong...

Comment: @vaku Can you expand your view on this? it may help me find the cause for this. I am unable to solve this issue mainly because I am unable to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: You can read about ping-pong [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Pings_and_Pongs_The_Heartbeat_of_WebSockets) | did your node js client use same technique that you used for creating server ... ? Are you using browser as a client....?

Comment: @vaku In this case the client is the nodejs application. Server is the MT5 application in which I am running a TCP Server Socket connection. this is the code I am using: https://www.mql5.com/en/code/169 I am not sure if you aware of MT5 or MQL5.

Comment: Ya, I am not aware about MT5 or MQL5 | did you write the websock implementation on MT5 yourself...? Or it is provided by library like in nodejs...

Comment: @vaku no, the link i gave contains entire client and server example. In that zip there is .exe file which is a small application connecting to local ip and port and data seems to stream continuously for hrs without issues but when i implement tcp on nodejs to get same data, my tcp for some reasons halts after few mins without flagging any error

Comment: What do you get if you listen for error events? `sock.on('error', function(err) { console.error("error:", err);  });`  There are a whole mess of other events too. https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listening

Comment: @O.Jones let me try adding and see. if it throws any error.

Comment: For what it's worth this isn't a Websocket application, it's a tcp socket application.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API I took off the websocket tag.

Comment: @O.Jones data streaming stops without any error thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue arises from your use of the pipe mechanism to echo back data which is never consumed on the original side (communication is unidirectional):

```
sock.pipe(sock);
```

This makes your code work as an echo server. Your socket "sock" is a duplex stream (i.e. both readable - for the incoming data you receive, and writable - for outgoing data you send back).

A quick fix if you don't need to respond back and you just need to receive data is to **simply delete the "sock.pipe(sock);" line**. To find out the explanation, read ahead.

Most probably your data source (the MT5 application you mentioned) sends data continuously and it doesn't read what you send back at all. So, your code keeps echoing back the received data using sock.pipe(sock), filling the outgoing buffer which is never consumed. However, the pipe mechanism of Nodejs streams handles **backpressure**, which means that when two streams (a readable and a writable one) are connected by a pipe, if the outgoing buffer is filling (reaching a high watermark), the readable stream is paused, to prevent the "overflow" of the writable stream.

You can read more about backpressure in the [Nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/es/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/). This fragment particularly describes how streams are handling backpressure:

> In Node.js the source is a Readable stream and the consumer is the Writable stream [...]
>
> The moment that backpressure is triggered can be narrowed exactly to the return value of a Writable's .write() function. [...]
>
> In any scenario where the data buffer has exceeded the highWaterMark or the write queue is currently busy, .write() will return false.
>
> When a false value is returned, the backpressure system kicks in. It will pause the incoming Readable stream from sending any data and wait until the consumer is ready again.

Below you can find my setup to show where backpressure kicks in; there are two files, server.js and client.js. If you run them both, server will write to console "BACKPRESSURE" soon. As the server is not handling backpressure (it ignores that sock.write starts returning false at some point), the outgoing buffer is filled and filled, consuming more memory, while in your scenario, socket.pipe was handling backpressure and thus it paused the flow of the incoming messages.

The server:

```
// ----------------------------------------
// server.js

var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    console.log('new connection');
    
    // socket.pipe(socket); // replaced with socket.write on each 'data' event

    socket.setEncoding('utf8');
    socket.setKeepAlive(true);

    socket.on("data", function (d) {
        console.log("received: ", d);
        var result = socket.write(d);
        console.log(result ? 'write ok' : 'BACKPRESSURE');
    });

    socket.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('client error:', err);
    });

    socket.on('end', function () {
        console.log('client disconnected');
    });
});

server.listen(10777, '127.0.0.1', () => {
    console.log('server listening...');
});
```

The client:

```
// ----------------------------------------
// client.js

var net = require('net');

var client = net.createConnection(10777, () => {
    console.log('connected to server!' + new Date().toISOString());

    var count = 1;
    var date;
    while(count < 35000) {
        count++;

        date = new Date().toISOString() + '_' + count;
        console.log('sending: ', date);
        client.write(date + '\n');
    }
});

client.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('received:', data.toString());
});
client.on('end', () => {
    console.log('disconnected from server');
});
```

Comment: I tried without sock.pipe and it worked perfectly fine, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for sharing this valuable info. I have one question. If in future for some reason I need client and server socket to communicate in bidirectional manner then sock.pipe would need to be added? and of the server side consumes data there wont be any issues of backpressure?

Comment: You can simply use socket.write to respond back if you do not have loads of data continuously going through or complex, slow operations on the receiving end. This is the simplest scenario. But if you have lots of data which must be handled at high throughput (e.g. zipping large binaries), the things are different - you probably would pipe the incoming data through a [transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) before piping it back to the outgoing stream. Note that here both the  incoming&outgoing streams are your socket, which is a duplex stream.

Comment: And, yes, if the other side consumes the data as fast as you send the data to it, you won't have any backpressure issues.